# Hibernate criteria groupProperty

Tags: hibernate, criteria

This question is about using Hibernate `Criteria` for doing a `group by`.
Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT s.name, max(p.price), min(p.price)
FROM supplier s, product p
WHERE s.supplier_id = p.supplier_id
GROUP BY s.name
```

I tried the following:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Supplier.class); 

Criteria prodCrit = criteria.createCriteria("products"); 

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList(); 
projList.add(Projections.max("price"));
projList.add(Projections.min("price")); 
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("name"));
prodCrit.setProjection(projList);
List list = criteria.list();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: price of: com.gtc.hibernate.query.Supplier
```

Answer (score 5):

Try createAlias instead of createCriteria.  It will yield a SQL query.

```
select 
       max(p1_.price) as y0_, 
       min(p1_.price) as y1_, 
       this_.name as y2_ 
from Supplier this_ 
   inner join Product p1_ on this_.id=p1_.supplier_id 
 group by this_.name;
```

Criteria :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Supplier.class); 
criteria.createAlias("products","p");

ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList(); 
projList.add(Projections.max("p.price"));
projList.add(Projections.min("p.price")); 
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("name"));
criteria.setProjection(projList);
List list = criteria.list();
```